# Dividing a 2xn rectangle into 2x1 rectangles

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

How many possibilities are there of dividing a 2xn rectangle to smaller 2x1 rectangles? (if we lay the big rectangle horizontally) I observed that either the small rectangle must be vertical, or a pair of two 2x1 horizontal rectangles on top of each other (in a 2x2 square) like a sandwich. any other formation will not have a "flat" end.

So if all the 2x1 rectangles are vertical, that's 1 way.

Then I can choose 2 adjacent (vertical) rectangles and "rotate" them to form the sandwich shape. this adds n-1 possibilities.

I can choose 2 pairs of adjacent rectangles to from 2 sandwiches and this adds, I believe, n(n+1)/2 possibilities.

But how do I keep going?

Comment: $n=1$ one way, $n=2$ two ways, $n=3$ three ways, $n=4$ five ways, etc.

Comment: How do I express that in terms of n?

Comment: I suggest you explore further first....

Comment: The two pairs of adjacent rectangles and the remaining $n-4$ vertical rectangles together are $n-2$ objects, among which you can choose the position of the two pairs, so there are only $\binom{n-2}2=(n-2)(n-3)/2$ different choices. It's often a good idea to check your results for small numbers. For $n=4$, there's clearly exactly one possibility, whereas your expression $n(n+1)/2$ would predict $10$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain a configuration for a $2\times n$ rectangle, you can either append a vertical tile to a $2\times(n-1)$ rectangle, or two horizontal tiles to a $2\times(n-2)$ rectangle. Thus the count $a_n$ of such configurations satisfies the recurrence relation $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$. Also, clearly $a_0=1$ and $a_1=1$. You might recognize this recurrence relation and these initial conditions from the [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).